# Sorting files in Bash using filenames

Tags: bash, escaping, mv, quoting

I'm trying to use a Bash script to sort my photo and video files. The files have a simple format "YYYY-MM-DD hh.mm.ss" (e.g. 2017-10-26 17.31.36.JPG). I would like to sort the files into folders according to the year and month. Here's the script that I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
LC_ALL=C
photo_path="/share/Usb/Temp/test/"
declare months
months=(["1"]="Jan\ " ["2"]="Feb\ " ["3"]="Mar\ " ["4"]="Apr\ " ["5"]="May\ " ["6"]="Jun\ " ["7"]="Jul\ " ["8"]="Aug\ " ["9"]="Sep\ " ["10"]="Oct\ " ["11"]="Nov\ " ["12"]="Dec\ ")

for filename in *; do
    str_len=$(expr ${#filename})
    year=$(echo $filename | cut -c1-4)
    month_num=$(echo $filename | cut -c6-7)
    short_year=$(echo $filename | cut -c3-4)     
    month=${months[$month_num]}$short_year'/'
    dest="$photo_path$year/$month."
    first_name=$(echo $filename | cut -c1-10)
    second_name=$(echo $filename | cut -c12-$str_len)
    name="$first_name\ $second_name"

    if [[ $year =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]];
    then
        echo "Moving $name to $dest"
        mv "$name" "$dest"
    fi

done
```

When I run the script, however, I get an error code like this

```
Moving 2017-10-26\ 17.31.36.JPG to /share/Usb/Temp/test/2017/Oct\ 17/.
mv: can't rename '2017-10-26\ 17.31.36.JPG': No such file or directory
```

Following the comments, I amended the code to:

```
for filename in *; do
    year=${filename:0:4}
    month_num=${filename:5:2}
    short_year=${filename:2:2}
    month=${months[$month_num]}$short_year'/.'
    dest="$photo_path$year/$month"

    if [[ $year =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]];
    then
        echo "Moving $filename to $dest"
        mv "${filename}" "${dest}"
    fi

done
```

However, I'm still getting the following error message:

```
Moving 2017-10-23 08.56.46.JPG to /share/Usb/Temp/test/2017/Oct\ 17/.
mv: can't rename '2017-10-23 08.56.46.JPG': No such file or directory
```

May I know what I should do to fix the code?

Comment: `str_len=$(expr ${#filename})` is `str_len=${#filename}` you do not need `expr` or the *command substitution*. You do not need `cut`, bash provides *parameter expansion with substring removal* that can trim off either end of a string to reach the desired part -- without spawning subshells calling utilities. The rest of your code has similar issues. You can escape, or quote, but not both for `name` -- think about it.

Comment: What does [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) say about your script?

Comment: Quote strings **or** escape spaces with a backslash, not both.

Comment: Instead of `month_num=$(echo $filename | cut -c6-7)` you can use `month_num=${filename:5:2}` etc

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm a real noob with Bash. I've since removed the escape spaces and amended the code accordingly.

Comment: Also a good idea to use `mv -- "${filename}" "${dest}"` in case your filename starts with `-`.

Comment: Fixed the bug and it works now. Thanks!